# Chrome extension popup resets even after changing its contents

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, I had to change popup html from background. Changes affects then and after clicking again in extension icon, the unchanged popup is showing. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you click away from your popup window, the window is reset. A way to fix this would be to use your background page to store session data, in your popup.js, do something like this:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bg){
  if(bg.myDataHTML){
    document.body.innerHTML = bg.myDataHTML; 
  }
  setInterval(function(){
    bg.myDataHTML = document.body.innerHTML
  },1000);    

  //do the rest of your work here.
})
```

I typically do everything in my popup inside that anonymous function to give me access to the libraries defined within my background page.

Comment: What's `sessionDataHTML`? I can't find anything on the internet!

Comment: sessionDataHTML is just something I made up to demonstrate storing html data in the background window object and then using it in the popup page.

Comment: So I have a `popup.html` with a `popup.js` loaded into it, do I paste this code in `popup.js` or `background.js` ?