# How to keep script running when extension popup is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I keep the script in the extension running?

I've got a popup.html and my script needs to run on this popup.html. I set the timer, I'm starting it and it starts to count down, once I close the popup, the timer stops. Apparently, the whole popup.html is unloaded once I click away.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension popup resets even after changing its contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621666/chrome-extension-popup-resets-even-after-changing-its-contents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Web Workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

These run in the background indepently from your window context.

**Edit:** I just checked this again and as @wOxxOm correctly states in his comment you should use Background Pages in chrome extensions. The link provides an example: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages

Comment: This will probably satisfy my needs, it will require some learning tho, but it'll be worth it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help. Web Workers are not as tricky as you might think, I would recommend to try it first with a simple task.

Comment: Wrong answer. A web worker inside the browserAction popup will be terminated just the same when the page is closed. The proper solution is a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

Comment: @wOxxOm This is not a wrong answer, popups are not supposed to run in background, but we need them to run as long as the page runs sometimes and not get reset every time we click away. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621666/chrome-extension-popup-resets-even-after-changing-its-contents

Comment: @Shayan, the popup is a separate page which is not related to the web page in the tab so your comment doesn't seem related. The answer is still wrong for the original question here.